# mysql order by timestamp desc with limit range not working

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, limit

my mysql table along with other fields has a time stamp field where i store the unix timestamps(ones like 13076829212). i want to make an ajax request which will fetch the newly added rows ordered by timestamp in descending order(fetch most recent) so i send the last row number to fire a query like this

```
select id, name from tablename order by timestamp desc limit 30, 125273733849448
```

i want to fetch all the rows in the most recent sequence starting from the last row number that was fetched.

What the above query is doing is fetching random records. i know my query logic is somewhere wrong, please help. thanks.

Comment: what is your idea? when you use limit x,y then x is starting point and y is how many records will be shown. So this query will actually skip first 30 results(with DESC order). Is that desirable?

Comment: idea is to fetch all the rows added after my last result set was fetched. thats why y is a large number to show all the records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated answer after discussions:**

Now that I understand the question a bit better I think you should use:

```
SELECT id, name, timestamp FROM tablename WHERE timestamp > [saved timestamp] ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Where `[saved timestamp]` would be replaced by the latest timestamp in the initial query.

If the initial query also uses `ORDER BY timestamp DESC` you will know that the latest timestamp is always in the first row so it can easily be saved.

---

**Original answer:**

If I understood this correctly 30 would be the id of the last row you fetched and id is incrementing. Then this should do it:

```
SELECT id, name FROM tablename WHERE id > 30 ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Comment: actualy 30 is the number of the last row, i mean 30th is the last row. should i do it using last id and not by the count of the row? what i want to do is fetch newly added rows using long polling

Comment: if i should be using last id, this sparks a new problem as initially the first query to generate a list is also in descending order so how will i be able to fetch the last id inside the resultset while looping. should i use the max(id)?

Comment: Perhaps you can save the last timestamp instead?

Comment: but then again to store the last timestamp, i will have to search for the highest timestamp value when i loop through the initial result. can i fire two queries, one for the looping and one just to fetch the highest timestamp or id value(using max) and then send that value and at the time of long polling use the query which u suggested.

Comment: if you order by timestamp in the initial query then you will know where the highest timestamp value is.

Comment: thats the point how will i get to know? i was trying to get the highest id but because the query was in descending order, it was giving me the first id.

Comment: I updated my answer to try and clarify. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24707/discussion-between-ellak-and-coder101)

Comment: it makes much more sense now but only thing how can i get to know the timestamp value of first row inside the while loop? i mean, i'm sorry i may be asking a silly question but.. i'm using $counter = 0 before the while loop starts and when if(++$counter == $numrows){$last == $row[timestamp]} but this gives me first rows timstamp